# Which parts of Franky's body have remained organic?

Tags: one-piece

I saw a picture from the parts when Franky visits the Future Kingdom (I haven't reached those parts of the series actually, so I don't know the context), with his metallic skull, chest, and other body parts exposed, as lacking skin coverage.

It was also visible on the way to Enies Lobby that his hip can be attached in length (reversed Centaur ability), but in the post-EL episodes people were disgusted by him running around naked, meaning he's likely not different from a typical male in this aspect.

Considering these and a lot other moments (such as the cola fridge replacing his stomach), it's pretty hard and almost impossible to determine how much of him remained human.

Is there anything we can know for sure? What I could judge so far is that his arms are *entirely* replaced (which is obvious seeing his post-TS appearance), but I was surprised that even his skull isn't original anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that because Franky couldn't reach his back when he first reconverted himself into a cyborg, that part still remains organic; and according to Senor Pink in chapter 775, Franky's back is still made of flesh after the timeskip.

Robin also managed to squeeze his privates at the end of the post-Enies Lobby arc in an attempt to get him to join, so these parts remained organic as well.

While his head is now partially robotic, as shown with his steel nose and the exposed circuitry from the injuries he suffered from his fight with Senor Pink, it can still bleed, showing that it remains at least partially organic.

Comment: What I couldn't get is that how could he split his hip (Reversed Centaur) if his privates are still original?